# Get the username displayed in the textbox automatically in wix

Tags: wix

I have  developed a screen that asks the admin username and password.My requirement is that I want the admin user and domain name to be displayed automatically on the screen in the username label.How can i do that please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (untested). WIX accepts environment-variables with `[%variable]`

```
<Control Id="Uname" Text="[%USERNAME]" Type="Text">
<Control Id="Udomain" Text="[%USERDOMAIN]" Type="Text">
```